Volume of Quarter-Circle with Square Slices
The question is: Find the volume of a solid with a base of a quarter-circle having radius 5, such that all the cross-sections which are perpendicular to one radius of the quarter-circle, are squares.
Can someone explain specifically why the integral $$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (5 \ \text{cos} \ \theta)^2 \,d\theta$$
is not the correct way to answer this question?
I understand that the integral $$\int_{0}^{5} (25 - x^2) \,dx$$ yields the right answer, but it feels like these should both be right.

There are several things confusing about the first paragraph. Is the base in the $xy$ plane? Are the two legs of the quarter circle along the $x$ and $y$ axes? Are the cross sections orthogonal to $x$ axis? If the answers to all these questions are all yes, then I can see how the last integral gives the right answer.

Th answer to all of those questions is yes. Sorry for the ambiguity

In that case, one obvious reason why your first integral wouldn’t give the correct answer is that it doesn’t have the right dimension. If you replace $5\to a$, then it scales as $a^2$, whereas volume should scale as $a^3$.

But how is that different in the second?

In the second, the integrand scales as $a^2$ and the upper limit of the integral scales as $a$, so the overall integral scales as $a^3$, which is the expected scaling.

The short answer is that your first integral does not correctly account for that thickness of a thin slice of the volume at angle $\theta$. To formulate the correct integral, you can start with a Riemann sum that approximates the volume you are interested in and then take a limit.
Let's start with the integral in $x$. (But I'll call it $y$ instead.) Divide the interval along the $y$-axis from $0$ to $5$ into $n$ small subintervals with subdivision points $y_0$, $y_1$, ... $y_n$. Denote the $x$-coordinates of the corresponding points on the radius $5$ circle $x_0$, $x_1$, ..., $x_n$. The slice of your volume between points $y_i$ and $y_{i+1}$ has thickness $y_{i+1}-y_i$ and cross sectional area approximately $x_i^2=5^2-y_i^2$. Hence we arrive at the Riemann sum
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(25-y_i)^2(y_{i+1}-y_i).
$$
By taking the limit as the spacing between subdivision points goes to zero and the number of points goes to infinity, we arrive at your second integral.
Now let's do the calculation in the angle variable. Divide the angular interval from $0$ to $\tfrac{\pi}{2}$ into $n$ subintervals with division points $\theta_0$, $\theta_1$, ..., $\theta_n$. The coordinates of the corresponding points on the radius $5$ circle are $(x_0,y_0)$, $(x_1,y_1)$, ..., $(x_n,y_n)$. The volume of the slice of volume between $\theta_i$ and $\theta_{i+1}$ has cross sectional area approximately $x_i^2=(5\cos\theta_i)^2$. Its thickness is
$$
y_{i+1}-y_i = 5\sin\theta_{i+1}-5\sin\theta_i.
$$
Write $\theta_{i+1} = \theta_i+\Delta\theta$ so that
$$
\sin\theta_{i+1} = \sin\theta_i\cos\Delta\theta+\cos\theta_i\sin\Delta\theta.
$$
Since $\Delta\theta$ is going to be very small, we have
$$
\cos\Delta\theta\approx1-\tfrac{1}{2}(\Delta\theta)^2, \quad\sin\Delta\theta\approx\Delta\theta.
$$
Putting this all together, the thickness of the slice is given by
$$
y_{i+1}-y_i\approx5\sin\theta_i\left(1-\tfrac{1}{2}(\Delta\theta)^2\right)+5\cos\theta_i\Delta\theta-5\sin\theta_i\approx5\cos\theta_i\Delta\theta,
$$
where the quadratic term in $\Delta\theta$ has been dropped. So the Riemann sum is
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(5\cos\theta_i)^2\cdot5\cos\theta_i(\theta_{i+1}-\theta_i).
$$
Taking the limit as the spacing between subdivision points goes to zero and the number of points goes to infinity, we arrive at the integral
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2}(5\cos\theta)^2\cdot5\cos\theta\,d\theta.
$$
This contains the factor that was missing from your integral.
